# Uploading files to google Drive using Flask

Tags: python, flask, drive

I am trying to upload files to Google Drive using Flask. If I try to upload a file with a python script passing the file as a parameter in the command line I have no issue, the file is uploaded correctly.
The script that works is:

```python
import os
import sys

try:
   from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
   from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
except ImportError:
   print("[!] Install Google Drive module. Use: pip install pydrive")
   sys.exit(1)

try:
   gauth = GoogleAuth()           
   drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
except ImportError:
   print("[!] Google Authentication Failed")
   sys.exit(1)

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
   print(f"USAGE: {sys.argv[0]} filetouoload")
   sys.exit(1)

class Drive:
    def __init__(self):
       self.folderId = 'folderID'
       self.content = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")

    def _uploadFile(self):
       gfile = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'output.png','parents': [{'id':self.folderId}]})
       gfile.SetContentFile(self.content)
       gfile.Upload() # Upload the file.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Drive().run()
```

However, if a try to do the same process using Flask through an html form, it doesn't work.
My flask application is (index.html, main.py):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Drive File Upload</h1>

    <form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        {{form.file()}}
        {{form.submit()}}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```python
 from flask import Flask, render_template
 from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
 from google.protobuf import service
 from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload
 from wtforms import FileField, SubmitField
 from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
 import os
 from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
 from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
 from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/files'

 class UploadFileForm(FlaskForm):
    file = FileField("File", validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Upload File")

 @app.route('/', methods=['GET', "POST"])
 @app.route('/home', methods=['GET', "POST"])
 def home():
    form = UploadFileForm()
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    folderId = 'folderID'
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       file = form.file.data  # First grab the file
       filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
       file.save(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
       path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
       gfile = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'output.png', 'parents': [{'id': self.folderId}]})
       gfile.SetContentFile(open(path, "rb"))
       gfile.Upload()
       return 'File has been uploaded.'
 return render_template('index.html', form=form)


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True)
```

The error that I get is: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BufferedReader

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2022 20:48:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2022 20:48:42] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py",    line 2528, in wsgi_app
       response = self.handle_exception(e)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
       rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
       return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
    File "/Users/elenamorabajen/Desktop/Flask-File-Uploads-main/main.py", line 40, in home
       gfile.SetContentFile(open(path, "rb"))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 169, in SetContentFile
       self.content = open(filename, 'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BufferedReader
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2022 20:48:42] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2022 20:48:42] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2022 20:48:42] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

I've tried different things but nothing has worked so far.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Including the full stack traceback of the error you received (formatted as a block of code) will help users answer your question.

Comment: How do you usually authenticate? Through command line (which opens up a browser) or you render a google auth page?

Comment: A browser window opens, there it asks the user if they want to access the app, if you accept, the file is uploaded.

Comment: were you able to solve this, i have the same problem